# Puppeter, stop/start proxy in the middle of running

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i have a program that consumes way too much data on proxies, so i was wondering if i could use a proxy just in the moment of an important block of instructions and then turn it off after that

I haven't seen any code that specifies how to do this, even though i've researched a in few sites